# How can I limit files in S3 based on their extension?

Tags: amazon-s3

I'm serving a static website using an Amazon S3 bucket.  I know that I can limit read access to certain "folders" (really keys, since S3 doesn't have folders) but what I'd really like to do is limit access by file extension.

In other words, I want to say "give read access to everyone for any file in this bucket, as long as that file ends in htm/css/js/png"; is that possible?

(As an aside, my concern is that I will accidentally upload a .git file, or something similar that I don't want to show to the world; setting a security policy to prevent such files from being shown seems safer than trusting myself to never accidentally upload the wrong file).

Comment: Is there really no one who is knowledgeable about S3 on Stack Overflow?  Or is there something wrong with my question ...?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You can write a [Bucket Policy](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/writebucketpolicy.html). You can use regular expressions to define which objects are affected by your policy ([examples](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/AccessPolicyLanguage_UseCases_s3_a.html)).

Your policy will be something similar to :

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "auniqueid",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
```

This will deny access to all `jpg` files of the buket `bucket`.

Comment: Thanks for those links, but none of the examples you linked shows how to limit by file extension (which was the specific question I was trying to get answered).

Comment: @machineghost added an example to my answer.

Comment: small comment: replace the version string with "2012-10-17" as it's obsolete